# Cannot convert string to list error

Tags: c#, list

```
    public void saveSettings()
    {
        refreshSettings();
        userSettings.sword = swordEquiped;
        userSettings.staff = staffEquiped;
        userSettings.bow = bowEquiped;
        userSettings.overalldamage = overallDamage;
        userSettings.silver = silver;
        userSettings.gold = gold;
        userSettings.exp = exp;
        userSettings.level = level;
        userSettings.physical = physicalDamage;
        userSettings.magic = magicDamage;
        userSettings.ranged = rangedDamage;
        userSettings.inventory = string.Join(", ", itemsBought.ToArray());
        userSettings.Save();
    }
    public void loadSettings()
    {
        exp = userSettings.exp;
        level = userSettings.level;
        swordEquiped = userSettings.sword;
        staffEquiped = userSettings.staff;
        bowEquiped = userSettings.bow;
        overallDamage = userSettings.overalldamage;
        silver = userSettings.silver;
        gold = userSettings.gold;
        physicalDamage = userSettings.physical;
        magicDamage = userSettings.magic;
        rangedDamage = userSettings.ranged;
        nameChosen = userSettings.username;
        itemsBought = userSettings.inventory;
    }
```

I have a `List<string>` named `itemsBought` and it has 3 values which are just item names `"Short Sword", "Shortbow", "Staff of Energy"`. I'm wondering how I can get the list to a string because this works:

```
userSettings.inventory = string.Join(", ", itemsBought.ToArray());
```

but when I try to load it with:

```
itemsBought = userSettings.inventory;
```

It can't convert it, giving me an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`.

Comment: "but when I try to load it with: itemsBought = userSettings.inventory; It can't convert it" means what?

Comment: load settings Settings userSettings = new Settings();

Comment: I can save it as userSettings.inventory = string.Join(", ", itemsBought.ToArray()); but when I try to load it, it throws an error

Comment: Please show the definition of the `userSettings.inventory` property and the `itemsBought` property.

Comment: userSettings.inventory is just "Solution name => Proporties => Settings => "inventory, string, user, value: nothing". and the list is just List<string> itemsBought = new List<string>();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, change your join string to `","` (no space), then try this:

```
itemsBought = userSettings.inventory.Split(',').ToList();
```

or perhaps this (maybe you have an implicit conversion from some `InventoryItem` class to type `string` so need to recreate those):

```
itemsBought = userSettings.inventory
   .Split(',')
   .Select(s => new InventoryItem(s))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: ahh, thanks. It worked. however, it comes up as "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],Short Sword" which, I want to keep "Short Sword" but how do I get rid of the rest?

Comment: Run your program in debug mode and step through the code. Ensure that the value of `userSettings.inventory` is a string with the value `Short Sword,Shortbow,Staff of Energy`. It sounds like one of your items that you're joining is not a string type, but a `List` of strings. You need to loop through them, perhaps, and do the right thing with each item (converting lists to their own strings and using strings directly).

Comment: userSettings.inventory IS the list. userSettings.inventory.Split(',').ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it back to an array using string.Split()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;

public class SplitTest {
    public static void Main() {

        string words = "This is a list of words, with: a bit of punctuation" +
                       "\tand a tab character.";

        string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' });

        foreach (string s in split) {

            if (s.Trim() != "")
                Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
// The example displays the following output to the console: 
//       This 
//       is 
//       a 
//       list 
//       of 
//       words 
//       with 
//       a 
//       bit 
//       of 
//       punctuation 
//       and 
//       a 
//       tab 
//       character
```